# What are tutorials in conferences?

Tags: conference

In addition to the main sessions, the workshops, and the special sessions, many conferences provide also some **tutorials**, usually the day before the beginning of the event or the day after the end of the event.

Computer science [NIPS conference](http://nips.cc/), for example, is one of these.

I've attended some of them, and I know what they are. But, if I talked with colleagues about tutorials, each of them would give a different definition of this conference aspects.

**What actually are tutorials in conferences?**

Are they specific lectures for young attendees of the conference?

Are they specific talks to give the guests the opportunity to explain and advertize a particular aspect of their research?

Or are they just a way to add one day to the conference schedule?

Comment: I think of a tutorial as an extended lecture, or series of lectures, intended to give a broad view of a particular area of research, rather than being focused on the speaker's own contributions.  But each conference organizer and/or speaker may have different plans.

Answer (score 4):

I think this varies a lot from field to field. In High-performance Computing and Scientific Computing, tutorials are very likely to be a set of lectures and hands-on laboratory sessions giving attendees instruction in how to use a computer, API, or other software. This could include "Programming for Intel Xeon Phi", "Introduction to Computing System X", "Python for HPC", etc. (many of which I have personally been involved in teaching). These kinds of tutorials are typical of conferences like *Supercomputing* and *IEEE Cluster*.

Answer (score 2):

At the conferences I attend, the tutorials tend to be sort of an oral survey of a topic, introducing practitioners (young or old) to a coherent body of work likely to be of interest to them.  For example, a person might give a detailed "how to" introduction to a new (or newly imported) set of methods that many people are interested in applying, or might present a coherent picture of important results within a subfield.